# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, module, dataset, attributeerror, lda

I have installed LDA plibrary (using pip)
I have a very simple test code (the next two rows)

> import lda
>
> print lda.datasets.load_reuters()

But i keep getting the error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'

in fact i get that each time i access any attribute/function under lda!

Comment: Do you have a module named `lda.py` or `lda.pyc` in the current directory?

Comment: You gave me a good direction to find the issue...
it is silly mistake of mine that i named my py file 'lda.py'
so python got confused and didn't load the LDA library due to that!

Thanks John
[if you submit an answer i will vote for it]

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a module named `lda.py` or `lda.pyc` in the current directory?

If so, then your import statement is finding that module instead of the "real" lda module.

Comment: my own mistake was that i named my python program with same name 'lda.py' which confused the python !
in order to fix i just renamed my own program (and delete lda.pyc as well)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the some error in **mmcv** library and solve it with

```
pip install --upgrade packaging
```

here is reference [link](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/5724#issuecomment-1016415834), hope this could help you.