# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I updated my computer today, and am getting the following error message when I attempt to import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd        
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I have tried the suggestions from the following links:

1. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537125/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-version)
2. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537125/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-version)

I do not have any files names numpy.py other than the numpy package.

I am running anaconda2 within windows 10, and have created a python 3.5 virtual environment.

Following is the full error message:

```
Python 3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 16:03:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\j267156\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\sf35\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\Users\j267156\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\sf35\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    _np_version = np.__version__
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Edit: performing the following commands gives an error

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__file__)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__file__'
print(numpy.version.version)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'version'
```

Edit2: perfoming the following commands gives me the following errors:

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros(5)
#AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros'
vars(np).keys()
#dict_keys(['__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__loader__', '__doc__', '__path__'])
```

Edit3:  the following commands result in the following output:

```
import numpy as np    
In [7]: np.__path__
    Out[7]: _NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\j267156\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\envs\\sf35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy'])

    In [8]: np.__loader__
    Out[8]: <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader at 0x2033a3c8080>
```

Comment: what does `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)` say?

Comment: as well you can try import numpy; numpy.version.version
Out[1]: '1.14.3'

Comment: @AnthonySottile - I get this message: ----> 1 print(numpy.__file__)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: @NaN I get this response ----> 1 numpy.version.version

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'version'

Comment: Try ... import numpy as np .... errors such as ... module 'numpy' has no attribute 'xxx' seem to be associated with errors in installation

Comment: A strange lack of attributes.  What’s `vars(numpy).keys()`?

Comment: @DavisHerring  This is my output >>> vars(numpy).keys()
dict_keys(['__path__', '__loader__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__spec__', '__package__'])

Comment: @NaN I have tried installing and uninstalling both numpy and pandas with no success.  import numpy as np gives no error, although when i call np.zeros(5) I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros'

Comment: @ktj1989: OK: now what are the values `numpy.__path__`, `numpy.__loader__`, _etc._?

Comment: @DavisHerring calling the following items: In [7]: np.__path__
Out[7]: _NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\j267156\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\envs\\sf35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy'])

In [8]: np.__loader__
Out[8]: <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader at 0x2033a3c8080>

Comment: This error occurs in my application when using 1.14.3 on Linux.
If I do pip install --upgrade numpy (which upgrades to 1.14.5), the error goes away.

Comment: I also had this issue with numpy 1.15.2, but it resolved with 1.15.4

Answer (score 22):

#### Try this

In Jupyter notebook first uninstall the existing numpy by using `!pip uninstall numpy`.

Then install it `!pip install numpy`. Now restart the kernel (Python Notebook). It will work.

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/349 this is relevant as well.

Comment: This should be updated to use the modern `%pip install` magic. The use of an exclamation point with `pip` (and `conda`) can cause issues. The modern magics for `%pip` and `%conda` were added to insure installations to the proper environment, something the exclamation point alone fails to do. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern `%pip install` and `%conda install` magic commands.

Answer (score 7):

You may have named your program/script 'numpy'.
I also had that then i renamed my program and then it works.
It happens because when you name your program similar to a module the import attribute clashes between programs and modules

Comment: Thanks, I did not do that though.

Comment: That is what's happening - statsmodels has a file statsmodels/compat/numpy.py and similarly for pandas pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py. It casues these problems I think

Comment: Thanks! I'm new at Python and I named my little test `random.py` and got trouble with `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros'` and such. After renaming it to `test_random.py` and moved it to another folder than `~/test` it worked. Gobsmacked.

Answer (score 4):

Just had this issue after conda chose to update numpy from 1.13.3 to 1.14.3. Reverting numpy via procedure in http://blog.rtwilson.com/conda-revisions-letting-you-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-your-environment/ sufficed to recover functionality, followed by pinning the version in the environment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/349#issuecomment-449402168):

```
pip uninstall -y numpy
pip uninstall -y setuptools
pip install setuptools
pip install numpy
```

Comment: I have not...I was using a conda installation.  I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling conda.

Comment: Found existing installation: numpy 1.20.1

Then installed 1.21.2 worked! had this when importing google cloud

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today while I was running a "brew upgrade" on MacOS and upgrade failed on matplotlib.

<TLDR/>

I run pip (v 2.x) and pip3 installed. It turned out I had not installed numpy with pip3. I ran

```
pip3 install numpy
```

brew upgrade then ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

1. `pip uninstall -y numpy`
2. `pip uninstall -y setuptools`
3. `pip install setuptools` or `conda install setuptools`
4. `pip install numpy` or `conda install numpy`

Any one will work. Conda/pip