# Numpy Installed but getting error: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and programming. I referred multiple SO posts but couldn't able to resolve the issue.

Python version 3.6.4 :: Anaconda installation
Operating system: macOS Sierra version 10.12.6

I can see numpy (pip installation) installed if I ran conda list in terminal but importing numpy in juypter rasing 'error 'AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '**version**'

I referred this post: [AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311096/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-version)

1st solution didn't work, 2nd TBH I din't follow, 3rd one when I try it shows juypter kernel is busy but nothing further happens.

**Juypter error**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d9ee79f53c9f> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
      4 import statsmodels.api as sm
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
     23     _np_version_under1p14,
     24     _np_version_under1p15,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 # numpy versioning
----> 9 _np_version = np.__version__
     10 _nlv = LooseVersion(_np_version)
     11 _np_version_under1p14 = _nlv < LooseVersion("1.14")

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

**Terminal showing bumpy installation** 
numpy                     1.18.3

Comment: You probably named one of your own files `numpy.py`. Don't do that.

Comment: I checked and none of my file is named as numpy.py.

Answer (score 0):

Will need more information but in my opinion, when you are trying to import numpy it is conflicting with another file that you created with the name `numpy.py`. and instead of importing the module you are importing that file.

Try this to locate the file

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
```

it should look something like this: `\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'`

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep. I didn't do anything and today importing numpy is not throwing error any more. But there seems to be another issue. Now **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.api'** error comes up even though statsmodel version 0.10.1 is installed <pip> installation. what other information do you need?