# Can´t import qiskit, attribute error in numpy: " 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'default_rng'"

Tags: python, numpy, import, attributes, qiskit

I´m using Python 3 and I´m working in jupyter, when I try to import qiskit the following error is showed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-578b7f7e9727> in <module>
----> 1 import qiskit



~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\qiskit\quantum_info\synthesis\two_qubit_decompose.py in __init__(self, unitary_matrix)
    169         # D, P = la.eig(M2)  # this can fail for certain kinds of degeneracy
    170         for i in range(100):  # FIXME: this randomized algorithm is horrendous
--> 171             state = np.random.default_rng(i)
    172             M2real = state.normal()*M2.real + state.normal()*M2.imag
    173             _, P = la.eigh(M2real)

AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'default_rng'
```

Comment: what  numpy version?

Comment: can you show your code? It doesn't look like a `qiskit` error but a `numpy` error

Answer (score 8):

I got almost the same error as:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'default_rng'

with the numpy version of `'1.16.2'`

```
numpy.__version__
'1.16.2'
```

As a solution, either you need to put these lines at the top of your file:

```
import numpy
numpy.random.bit_generator = numpy.random._bit_generator
```

Or the your current numpy version probably is `<= 1.17`. Hence, you need to update the NumPy version. For instance, I have updated it on Anaconda environment as:

```
conda update numpy
```

And the current version is:

```
numpy.__version__
'1.19.2'
```

Updates take time because of lots of dependencies of NumPy. Hopefully, the issue is resolved on my side!

Answer (score 7):

You need NumPy 1.17 or later to have the new RNG functions that Qiskit needs

Comment: I´ve update numpy, but it´s in version 1.11.3, something wrong I must done while updating numpy. I´m going to check it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using jupyter in anaconda - uninstalling, reinstalling and **restarting the kernel** worked for me similar here: [AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311096/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-version)

1. !pip uninstall -y numpy
2. !pip install numpy
3. **RESTART KERNEL**