# AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, pycharm, xgboost, streamlit, pycaret

I'm receving this error (AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute '**version**')
while trying to build AutoML model using pycaret

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from ydata_profiling import profile_report
from streamlit_pandas_profiling import st_profile_report
import os
from pycaret.regression import setup,compare_models,pull,save_model
if os.path.exists('dataset.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=None)


if choice == "Perform modeling": 
    chosen_target = st.selectbox('Choose the Target Column', df.columns)
    if st.button('Run Modelling'):
        setup(df, target=chosen_target, verbose=False)
        setup_df = pull()
        st.dataframe(setup_df)
        best_model = compare_models()
        compare_df = pull()
        st.dataframe(compare_df)
        save_model(best_model, 'best_model')
```

I tried searching on google

Comment: Can you show us the whole traceback? What version are you using? Have you tried reinstalling the library?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311096/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-version) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537125/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-version) answer your question?